# SELECT Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck in a piece of code that does not quite understand.
I have several tables with different names but same fields, but the tables are independent
Something like that:

table1

- id
- user
- title

table2

- id
- user
- title

I need to get in the same query data from two tables but I fail, I try with INNER JOIN, UNION ALL, but not knowing, it misapplied.
Right now I have this:

```
$mysites = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("
select * 
FROM table1,table2
where table1.user = table2.user AND 
table1.user = 1");

foreach($mysites as $mysite){
echo $QUERY['title'];
}
```

**but returned this:**

title1.table1

title2.table1

**and i like this:**

title1.table1

title2.table1

title1.table2

title2.table2

A greeting and thanks

Comment: have you tried `select table1.*, table2.*` ?

Comment: What is `$mysites` and `$QUERY`? Are they defined? Note that case matters with PHP variables. What class are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, I tried this (select table1.*, table2.*)  but it gives the same result.

I've corrected the variable $mysites
Any more ideas?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17692215/2568469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword `UNION` like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2
```

This query will select everything from `table1` and merge the results with those from `table2`. Please note that you have to select the same number of columns from both tables. Moreover, column names and datatypes will be assigned according to first table.

If you want to preserve duplicates add the keyword `ALL`:

```
  SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear.....

Are the ID's the same in each table for each user? If so an INNERJOIN will help

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 

FROM table1.t1 

INNER JOIN table2.t2 

ON t1.id = t2.id 

WHERE t1.user = "1"
```

(Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN if the data could be missing)

If this is not the case, why not put the data from one table into the other, and have just one table with all the data in it?

Comment: This not return any value ...
Each table handles a lot of data and need to have them separated in 2 different tables.
Thanks for answering